# Facebook Graph API status update like Relationship

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm searching a few days on Facebook Api docs and on google to know how to make my status update be like the relationship status update, or when I add new friends. 
When te text is shown after the user name.
I attached a picture to show what I need.

[image]

Someone know how can I do that or something similar to help me search?
I'm using ASP.NET, but if you know how do that in PHP or any other language will be welcome.

Comment: If you can post the english translation of those lines, then someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using Graph APIs, these are generated when using the Facebook in a browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not so clear and you've not posted any of your current codes you're using, but i assume you're trying to status update using graph api?

To make status update on your wall, you need access_token and publish_stream permission granted by the user you want to post, here's what facebook's docs say:

> Publishing
>
> You can publish to the Facebook graph by issuing HTTP POST requests to
>   the appropriate connection URLs, using an access token. For example,
>   you can post a new wall post on Arjun's wall by issuing a POST request
>   to https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
>      -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
>      https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

If you're using PHP, then i can provide you with a snippet for authentication and for making status update, let me know what you're trying to do more clearly and with the code.

Comment: Dennis, I know how to publish to facebook wall using API, but I need my message like the picture posted.
I'm using ASP.NET to do that, but the sample code can be in PHP or .NET, I just need to know how it works and I'll search about it on Google.

Comment: @Diego: As per my information, that's not possible with graph api, those messages are from facebook system and not from applications, if you can get me any application which is doing that, then i can easily tell you how its done by analyzing it.

Comment: I have no images. And I'm not sure if there is any application that does this.
It would be useful to me if I could do this.

Comment: Those messages are from facebook system and not from applications and its surely not possible to do it using graph api, you can make status updates using graph api, that's similar to what you want.